# Withdrawal error from Trust wallet (backtracked) - what to do here?

Tags: error

I get constantly an error by withdrawing XTZ from the Trust Wallet (operation was backtracked because one of the subsequent operations in the same batch failed). I already set up the app again on my telephone, but this did not solve the issue.

Hopefully someone knows what to do here??

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "withdrawing XTZ". Do you mean you are trying to send it to another address? or performing some interaction with a smart contract? The most common cause of such issues is the wallet estimating fees incorrectly, you could retry the operation and try to send less than the entire balance of your wallet (e.g. leave 0.1 XTZ in your wallet). If this is not the issue, if you can find the transaction on tzkt.io and edit your question with the link, I can take a look at it